# How does this workflow result in discarded work?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I was linked to [this blog](http://www.randyfay.com/node/89) on another question, and I read this warning about a certain git workflow:

> Here's the actual scenario that caused an enormous amount of hair pulling.
>
> - The team was using the merge workflow. Lots of people changing things really fast. The typical style was
>
>   - Work on your stuff
>   - Commit it locally
>   - git pull and hope for no conflicts
>   - git push as fast as you can before somebody else gets in there
> - Many of the team members were using Tortoise Git, which works fine, but they had migrated from Tortoise SVN without understanding the underlying differences between Git and Subversion.
> - Merge conflicts happened fairly often because so many people were doing so many things
> - One user of Tortoise Git would do a pull, have a merge conflict, resolve the merge conflict, and then look carefully at his list of files to be committed back when he was committing the results. There were lots of files there, and he knew that the merge conflict only involved a couple of files. For his commit, he unchecked all the other files changes that he was not involved in, committed the results and pushed the commit.
> - The result: **All the commits by other people that had been done between this user's previous commit and this one were discarded**

I'm not sure I understand how this would happen? More specifically:

- How are you able to push the 'wrong' state you're in? As I thought I understood it, this would require a `--force`, but the story here is that this is turned off. Wouldn't the user need a `pull` in between commiting the conflict-fixes and pushing?
- Does discarded here even mean what I think it means? I'd have a hard time believing they are going to be 'removed', I suppose the actual result is more like that they are being undone?

Comment: What do you mean by "commits by other people that had been done between this user's previous commit and this one" ? Were the commits commited in that timeframe, or were they pushed?

Comment: Prime example of why everyone should be working on their own private branches, rather than everyone trying to work on e.g. `master`...

Comment: @Oznerol256 : I am not the origional writer of that quote, I'm just asking if i'm getting it right. I'm not sure what it means :)

Comment: @twalberg but surely there is merit to working on non-private branches? for collaboration? especially when it isn't the master branch?

Comment: @Nanne It's better in a distributed VCS to do all your work on a private branch, and then merge your work into a public branch. This results in much less traffic on the public branch(es), with a corresponding significant drop in the frequency of conflicts and other race conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "discarded" here means being undone (there are in history, but topmost commit is without changes). I think that the result is similar to having pulled changes and choosing `ours` merge strategy, i.e. choosing always own version over changes.

---

Step by step explanation of what I think happened

When ready to publish

```
*---*---*---A---B          <--- user's master

*---*---*---X              <--- public repository master
```

"*One user of Tortoise Git would do a pull*", which is fetch...

```
*---*---*---A---B          <--- master
         \         
          \-X              <--- origin/master (remote tracking branch)
```

...followed by attempted merge: "*have a merge conflict*"...

```
*---*---*---A---B---[C]          <--- master
         \          / 
          \-X------/
```

Now there is a bit of ambiguity:

> **resolve** the merge conflict, **and then** look carefully at his list of files to be committed back when he was committing the results. There were lots of files there, and he knew that the merge conflict only involved a couple of files. For his commit, he unchecked all the other files changes that he was not involved in, committed the results and pushed the commit.

My take on it is that "*resolve... and then*" should read "*resolved... by*", i.e. that said description is how user resolved merge, and not something done as separate step.  Resolving merge ends with committing it:

```
*---*---*---A---B----B'          <--- user's master
         \          / 
          \-X------/
```

where `B'` is result of using ours-like merge strategy, where conflicted files were taken from user's version, replacing / forgetting changes in `X`

Assuming that there were no other activity in public repository, the 'master' branch in it still looks like this:

```
*---*---*---X              <--- public repository master
```

and push will be fast-forward and succeed:

```
*---*---*---A---B----B'     <--- public repository master
         \          / 
          \-X------/
```

When somebody else will pull new changes, he/she would see state `B'`, which do not include changes from `X` because of mis-merge (incorrect manual conflict resolution).

Comment: But if you want to push after the merge, then you'd either need to pull first (so getting those changes), or use `--force` (which couldn't happen)? therefore my first question: how is it you can push this state without local 'knowledge' of those other commits?

Comment: @Nanne: from what **I** understand from the explanation it was *pull* followed by "discard other changes" *merge* and then fast-forward *push*.

Comment: I read it as that there were other changes after/during the merge, so I am confused that a ff push would even work? Maybe the changes were done on the same repo? While that is strange, otherwise I just don't get it. Maybe the first question is: who did this changes and where.

Comment: @Nanne: I have added step by step explanation of what I think happened, with ASCII-art graphs (hopefully readable)

Comment: But in this scenario nothing seems to go missing? Where do the "All the commits by other people" fit in? I assumed they were on the public repository master, and so have that in state Y, making a fast forward impossible.. I guess the issue isn't that big, and I was looking for real trouble. In your proposed explanation I cannot find those commits anywhere, but maybe they mean changes from X? In this scenario the only place you can fsck up is be pulling changes and then not merging correctly I guess? So you almost manually remove changes. Well, that's not a scenario to worry much about I think.

Comment: @Nanne: Yes, AFAIC the scenario is *not merging correctly*, and changes are not missing just manually *undone* in mis-merge.

Comment: meh, a lot of fuzz for a (as I see it) non issue. I was afraid of losing some `Y` commit on the external repo, but couldn't figure out how that would happen. But merging like a monkey, ingoring changes from `X`, and then uploading (and not verifiying / reviewing that change).. I'm not too scared of that :)

Answer (score 1):

Jakub's answer is correct, but if someone wants a shorter explanation, here it is:

No *commits* were lost, nor removed from the remote repository.  It's just that the merge commit reverted some *code* to a previous state.

The situation is similar to what happens when one uses `git revert` - imagine a history like this:

```
A---B---C---D
```

running `git revert B` would result in a new commit `b` that "undoes" the changes introduced by `B`.  The history is now

```
A---B---C---D---b
```

Commit `B` is still there, but it's changes are removed by commit `b`.

Comment: Looks about right and a bit shorter. It's indeed probably what the author meant, but it it not in the same league as the first problem imho (the push--force one)

Comment: There is a similarily here as well.  The thing with `push --force` is that you don't need it when you push a commit that is a descendant of the previously pushed commit.  A "revert commit" (`b` in my example) *is* a descendant of remote branch (`D`), so it can be pushed without `--force` even though it removes stuff.  Similarly, a merge commit is a descendant of previously pushed commit, regardless of however destructive changes that it may introduce.